# Prevent HTML <img> tags from Wrapping

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have JavaScript that dynamically creates many `<img>` tags and appends them to various divs.

I want to prevent these images from wrapping. That is, when the screen resolution is not enough to contain them, the browser should create horizontal scroll-bars instead of wrapping.

Answer (score 3):

Add the following CSS to the `div` containing the `img` tags:
`overflow-x: auto; white-space: nowrap;`
in order to get a horizontal scrollbar when the content is wider than the `div` and to prevent the content from wrapping.

Comment: I have many of these divs, so this works, but i have to set it only on the "container" div.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

in CSS

```
div {
 overflow: auto;
}
```

Comment: It's worth noting that this doesn't *strictly* observe the specific requirement of *horizontal scroll-bars*, `overflow-x: auto` might be better. But I'm not sure if the OP *meant* to specify only horizontal scroll-bars, or not.